# how to find the name that produced a Spring InvalidResultSetAccessException

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, sqlexception

I have a big web application and some times is hard to find the column name that  produced a org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException.
I use Spring 4.1.6 and the exception is throwed by SqlRowSet methods like:
sqlRowSet.getString("name")
sqlrowSet.getInt("number")
Is there a way to log the name that caused the exception?
Is there a way to override the getString, getInt, etc So that I add a system.out.println to log the column name that produced the exception?

Answer (score 0):

The `InvalidResultSetAccessException` wraps an `SQLException` that *may* have more information; e.g. in the message.  You can call `InvalidResultSetAccessException::getSQLException` to access it.   Note that the actual `SQLException` class and its message are likely to be database specific.

You could set a breakpoint on the line where the exception is thrown, then use the debugger to examine the context.

Apart from that ... no.  The code that looks up the column name does not either log it, or explicitly record it if there is an error.

---

<sup>I suppose you could create your own wrapper for the `SqlRowSet` object, but  "the cure is worse than the disease" ... as they say.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Spring data JPA using dictionary to check column name in database which existed